# C - win32 api for windows 8 desktop

Tags: winapi

I am a C programmer, I would know if the win32 api are compatible with windows 8,
if I write a C program using win32 api does it will work on windows 8?
If it doesn't work what api should I use?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want your API to quite simply work on desktop installations on Win8 then yes, it will probably work - but you should test it regardless.

If you want your API to be a Win8 marketpalce app, then I'm afraid you'll have to use C# or C++.

Comment: I want to program only for windows 8 desktop.

Comment: @blob any .exe file I have compiled via gcc under my Win8 installation worked just as it did with my win7 install. So you should be fine. But as I said - you will have to do the testing, I suppose that goes without question tho.

Comment: Windows Store applications target WinRT. With WinRT being essentially COM it can be consumed by any language capable of consuming a C interface. There is no "C# and C++" only. C is as much an option as VB.NET or C++/CX.

Comment: @IInspectable I always thought you are only going to be admitted to the Windows store via Visual Studio, which doesn't seem to support pure C. Where am I wrong?

Comment: Visual Studio **can** be used to deploy Windows Store applications. It is not required, though (see [App packages and deployment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464929.aspx)). Your assumption that VS doesn't support C is also unfounded (see [Compiling a C/C++ Program](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wk21sfcf.aspx)). You are also wrong in assuming that targetting WinRT is technologically different for C and C++ - it isn't. C++/CX is the same still, just a bit easier on the eye.

Comment: @IInspectable: I'll have to refresh my memory a lot it seems. Thank you.